# how to import domains from txt file to cpanel as alias domain with use of php

Tags: cpanel

I intend to import domains from `txt` file to `cpanel` as alias domains ,

My `cpanel` account use `https` protocol ,

I use shared host and have not access to `whm`,

I found [this](http://www.zubrag.com/forum/index.php/topic,396.msg1540.html) code but don't work in `https` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<?php

$cpanel_user = "";
$cpanel_passwd = "";
$cpanel_server = "";
$server_port = "2083"; // use 2082 for http
$theme = "paper-lantern"; 
$domains = file("domains.txt");

foreach($domains as $pdomain) {
        file_get_contents("https://$cpanel_user:$cpanel_passwd@$cpanel_server:$server_port/frontend/$cpanel_theme/park/doaddparked.html?domain=$pdomain&go=Add+Domain");

}

?>
```

Of course add the cpanel username/password and server there. Also http uses port 2082, https uses port 2083. Not sure if the script will be able to handle the cpanel session stuff (I do not have a cpanel account and a domain right now to test so I can't really check if the script is actually working or not). I have used the **paper_lantern** theme in the script since this is the default theme on the newer cPanel/WHM versions.